# how to call the static variable to non static method, i.e I need to call the maxId variable to insert method

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.5

```
public static List<Movie> movies;

static {
    movies = new ArrayList<>();
    movies.add(new Movie(1, "Fprd vs Ferrari", "Movie on Racing", "abcd", "xyz"));
    movies.add(new Movie(2, "F2", "Comedy Movie", "Venkatesh", "Tamanna"));
    movies.add(new Movie(3, "Titanic", "Movie", "Hero", "Heroine"));
    Movie max = Collections.max(movies, Comparator.comparingInt(Movie::getId));
    int maxId = max.getId();

}
```

```
public Result insert(Http.Request request) {
        JsonNode jsonNode = request.body().asJson();
        if (jsonNode == null) {
            return badRequest("insufficient movie information");
        }
                Movie movie = Json.fromJson(jsonNode, Movie.class);
               movies.add(movie);
               return ok(Json.toJson(movie));

    }
```

This is insert method. now I want access that maxId variable to insert method.
anyone can tell me how this one will cleared to get increment the id

Comment: read static block vs static variable. You are not talking about static variable but static code block.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's a local variable.

That is also not a static method, it's a static block. It is executed the first time the class is loaded in the memory, and not after that. If you want to keep that value, change your code to this:

```
private static int maxId;

static {
    movies = new ArrayList<>();
    movies.add(new Movie(1, "Fprd vs Ferrari", "Movie on Racing", "abcd", "xyz"));
    movies.add(new Movie(2, "F2", "Comedy Movie", "Venkatesh", "Tamanna"));
    movies.add(new Movie(3, "Titanic", "Movie", "Hero", "Heroine"));
    Movie max = Collections.max(movies, Comparator.comparingInt(Movie::getId));
    maxId = max.getId();
}
```

EDIT

What you can do is extract the last two lines to an actual method (either static or instance method):

```
public static int getMaxId() {
    Movie max = Collections.max(movies, Comparator.comparingInt(Movie::getId));
    return max.getId();
}
```

and call this as you would any other method.

Comment: after creating like how I access in method, how to call can u send the code please

Comment: Again: if you don't change your code, you can't access that variable/value. Store it as a class level static variable, and you'll be able to use it. The code is in my answer

Comment: now I want that maxId call to insert method to equal that maxId and movie object id value... ex that id is assign with movie object of id value

Comment: You can't call max.getId from your method, because you don't have that object there. You can also just remove the last two lines of that static block, and put them in your method

Answer (score 0):

In  this method we have to write this:

```
public Result insert(Http.Request request) {
        JsonNode jsonNode = request.body().asJson();
        if (jsonNode == null) {
            return badRequest("insufficient movie information");
        }
        String movieName = jsonNode.get("movieName").asText();
        boolean existmovie = containName(movieName);
        Movie movie = Json.fromJson(jsonNode, Movie.class);
        int nextId = Collections.max(movies, Comparator.comparingInt(Movie::getId)).getId();
        movie.setId(++nextId);
        if (existmovie == true) {
            return badRequest("Movie Already exist");
        }
        movies.add(movie);
        return ok(Json.toJson(movie));

    }
```